# Changing system proxy settings in Ubuntu 12.04 from terminal

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, configuration, proxy

I've been working in Ubuntu 12.04 and one of the things that I am trying to implement in a Bash script is modifying the proxy settings of the system. To clarify, this would be a script that sets up each VM that I make with the programs and packages that I need. I can find and edit the Proxy settings manually through System Settings and selecting Network, but my intention is to automate this part.

The code that I have tried up to now has been:

```
gconftool --set /system/http_proxy/host --type string *host*
gconftool --set /system/http_proxy/port --type int *port*
gconftool --set /system/http_proxy/use_http_proxy --type bool true
gconftool --set /system/http_proxy/use_same_proxy --type bool true
gconftool --set /system/proxy/mode                --type string manual
```

I have also tried the above with `gconftool-2`. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You must use new `gsettings` tool and not old gconftool, with a bit different keys:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.socks host '127.0.0.1'
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.socks port 3128
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'manual'

# to disable proxy:
# gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'none'
```

Comment: Can this set all proxy (http, https, ftp) for firefox? I'm still using 11.10, but Firefox has to be set manually from within Firefox. Actually I want to make a proxy settings script so that all program use the proxy I want, including svn.

Comment: Yes it instantly set proxy in Firefox. In my Firefox (ubuntu-bundled firefox, on Ubuntu 12.04) there is an option "Proxy settings manually through System Settings", I am using this, so only system settings needs to be changed.